# Is there a good tool that lets me sniff the network calls?

Tags: windows, itunes, http, url, sniffing

My objective:

Itunes talks to their cloud servers. I want to be able to know which URL they are talking to when I use my Itunes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if you want to also see the data being sent.  If you just want to see the hostnames/IP addresses that your applications are connecting to, you can use a more lightweight utility like [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) or Windows' built-in `netstat -b`.

Comment: I'd recommend [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)... seeing as it's not 2006.

Comment: Oops! ROFL...I forgot about their spiffy name change; thanks for the correction.  :)

Comment: Without a doubt, WireShark.